# Why do I get SocketTimeoutException when I have accept-count=100000?

Tags: java, performance, spring-boot, jmeter, load-testing

I'm load testing my Spring Boot server with JMeter and have

`application.properties`

```
server.tomcat.accept-count=100000
server.tomcat.max-threads=1000
```

`Application.java`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    ServerProperties serverProperties = context.getBean(org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties.class);
    Tomcat tomcat = serverProperties.getTomcat();
    Logger.getLogger(Application.class.getName()).info("acceptCount = " + tomcat.getAcceptCount());
    Logger.getLogger(Application.class.getName()).info("maxConnections = " + tomcat.getMaxConnections());
    Logger.getLogger(Application.class.getName()).info("maxThreads = " + tomcat.getMaxThreads());
```

`Console`

```
2019-10-24 20:22:31.174  INFO 57472 --- [  restartedMain] c.s.s.Application : acceptCount = 100000
2019-10-24 20:22:31.174  INFO 57472 --- [  restartedMain] c.s.s.Application : maxConnections = 10000
2019-10-24 20:22:31.175  INFO 57472 --- [  restartedMain] c.s.s.Application : maxThreads = 1000
```

`loadtest.jmx`

```
    <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
      <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
      <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">100</stringProp>
    </elementProp>
    <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">10000</stringProp>
    <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">10</stringProp>
```

(10,000 users x 100 loops = 1 million requests)

In JMeter `View Results Tree` I see the errors:

```
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Read timed out
```

The `Summary Report` shows it got up to 11,000 samples before errors stopped the test. I don't understand because with an accept count of 100,000, shouldn't it accept 100,000 connections in the queue before it starts to give rejections and cause JMeter to get a SocketTimeoutException?

---

I also tried `accept-count=10000`, `max-connections=1000`, and JMeter got up to 8000 samples, max time 12000ms (30s timeout on `HTTP Request`) and it gave the error `Response code: Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Connect to localhost:8080 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect`. It should at the very least queue 10,000 connections before refusing.

Comment: `accept-count` appears to be just the backlog argument to `listen()`. It doesn't have anything to do with 'Non-HTTP response message: read timed out', which merely says that the connection having been made (this ruling out backlog) and the request having been sent, no response was received with the timeout period, which might indicatea server being busy or having a deadlock or a bug.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html)

> **maxConnections**
>
> The maximum number of connections that the server will accept and process at any given time. **When this number has been reached, the server will accept, but not process, one further connection. This additional connection be blocked until the number of connections being processed falls below maxConnections at which point the server will start accepting and processing new connections again.** Note that once the limit has been reached, the operating system may still accept connections based on the acceptCount setting. The default value varies by connector type. For NIO and NIO2 the default is 10000. For APR/native, the default is 8192.

Therefore my expectation is that the server can work on 10k concurrent connections and the ones which are above are put into queue. If this is the behavior you want - just increase connect/response timeouts in JMeter's [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults/), the settings live under "Advanced" tab:

[image]

Comment: I have timeouts set to 30s to match production. I thought with 100,000 `accept-connect` it would accept nearly all the connections in the queue without timing out. I don't understand the series of events for queue, connect, timeout, response. I found the default is around 100. Maybe the computer (Windows) just cannot queue more than that or it really takes 30+s to queue?

Comment: You can use [Windows PerfMon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/perfmon) or [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/) to monitor network-specific metrics on your load generator machine(s), it might be the case you will need to increase i.e. [`MaxUserPort` and `TcpTimedWaitDelay` settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/technical-guides/settings-that-can-be-modified-to-improve-network-performance)